# C _fullpath() returning bad path

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi, path

I'm trying to retrieve the full path of a file using C language, but the `_fullpath` function always returns me a path such as `C:\Windows\system32\test.txt` instead of `C:\Users\me\Documents and settings\test.txt`

Here's the code I've wrote so far :

```
char lszValue[255];
DWORD dwType=REG_SZ;
DWORD dwSize=255;
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
char full[255];

if ((RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\MY\\TestReg", &hKey)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if ((RegQueryValueEx(hKey, TEXT("path"), NULL, &dwType,(LPBYTE)&lszValue, &dwSize)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(strcat(lszValue, "/*"), &FindFileData)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            WriteInLogFile("ERROR: FindFirstFile");
        do
        {
            if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (!_fullpath(full, FindFileData.cFileName, 255))
                WriteInLogFile("ERROR: _fullpath\r\n");
                WriteInLogFile(full);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0);
    }
}
```

Do someone has any idea about this issue please ?

Thanks !

Comment: what kind of computer are you using 32 bit or 64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the CWD first to the folder where the file is located. Because that's the folder which is used to construct the full path of the file.

That means, you have to call [_chdir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx) before _fullpath.

Answer (score 0):

Full path converts a relative path (relative to current directory) to a full path.  You need to set the current directory to the directory used for enumerating files if you want to convert them to full path.